# CSS - Size Two Divs Equally Side by Side within Containing Div

Tags: css

This seems very basic, but all the Google search's aren't helping me especially with a containing div.  Basically, I want two sections (either div's or preferably fieldsets's) on my page to be placed within a containing section, both be equally sized horizontally regardless of page width, placed side by side, and resize proportionally when the page is resized.  **One caveat is that that the containing section can have padding (such is the case with using fieldset), so the sub-containers need to be 50% of the base container's available width.** Here's an example of my sections.  Any suggestions are appreciated!

```
<fieldset>
  <legend>Contact Information</legend>
  <fieldset class="homeAddress">
    <legend>Home Address</legend>
    Address: 123 Main St.
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="workAddress">
    <legend>Work Address</legend>
    Address: 456 Second St.
  </fieldset>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to use `box-sizing: border-box` as thirtydot suggested (which I agree is the easiest solution), you could simply wrap your fieldsets in a couple divs, and set those to 50% width. Then you can apply whatever padding/styles you want to the inner fieldsets without having to worry about it affecting the 50% width.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/VQrYD/1/

The benefit is that you don't need to worry about browser support for the `box-sizing` CSS property.

Answer (score 4):

[`box-sizing: border-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/Box-sizing) is the best way to do this. It changes the `width` and `height` to include the `padding` and `border`.

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/FtBc4/2/

```
fieldset > fieldset {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 10px;

    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;

    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

The [browser support](http://caniuse.com/css3-boxsizing) is very good. The only unsupported browser that you might care about is IE7.

If you need to support IE7, then you can instead add some wrapper `div`s, [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/FtBc4/3/).

Comment: No problem. I just noticed that I duplicated your HTML instead of using the two `fieldset`s inside. Fixing..

Answer (score 0):

just use

```
width:50% (or a litte less if you want a gap or are using a border)
float:left
```

example http://jsfiddle.net/CQ9uU/

Comment: thanks but that's not quite what I'm looking for.  Here's a better sample http://jsfiddle.net/CQ9uU/6/ which renders fine in JSFiddle (minus not having the fieldset borders), but in Chrome, the fieldsets are on different lines.  I can set the widths to some other value like 47% which works for a wider page, but as the page gets narrower, they start "wrapping" again.  Basically, I want as the page gets smaller, that no wrapping (putting the right section below the left) will occur, and if needs be, the page will just display a horizontal scroll bar to display the info.